# Git: File Rename

Tags: macos, git, case-insensitive

I wanted to rename a folder from "`Frameworks`" to "`frameworks`", but git would not let me add the new lowercase name. I guess it treats filenames case insensitive, does it?

A `git add frameworks/ -f` didn't help

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can try:

- `"git mv -f foo.txt Foo.txt"` (note: this is [no longer needed since git 2.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979063/6309))
- to set `ignorecase` to false in the config file.

---

But the issue of case (on Windows for instance) is described in the [msysgit issue 228](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=228) (again: this should [now -- June 2014 --  work with git 2.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979063/6309))

> there is always an option to set `ignorecase` to false in the config file that will force Unix like Git semantics on top of NTFS.
> Git supports this behavior but it is not the default - from NTFS point of view `a.txt`
> and `A.txt` are the same thing - so Git tries to preserve that as most users would expect

> As a better workaround, you can
>
> ```
> git mv foo.txt foo.txt.tmp && git mv foo.txt.tmp Foo.txt
> ```
>
> , which also changes the case of the file as stored on disk.

This blog post [illustrates the same issue on MacOs](http://www.paperplanes.de/2008/9/24/git_bits_renaming_with_lowercase.html) during a rebase:

> The default on Mac OS X file systems is that they are case-insensitive. `FFFFFF.gif` is the same as `ffffff.gif`.
>
> If you delete the file in question, just from the file system, not from the Git index, mind you, you can merge the branch in question, and have it restore the file as if nothing happened.
>
> The steps are pretty simple:
>
> ```
> $ rm file/in/question.gif
> $ git merge trunk
> ```

---

Anyhow, [remember what git mv stands for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094269/whats-the-purpose-of-git-mv):

```
mv oldname newname
git add newname
git rm oldname
```

, so if `newname` and `oldname` clash, you need to make them different (even if it is only for a short period of time), hence the `git mv foo.txt foo.txt.tmp && git mv foo.txt.tmp Foo.txt`

Comment: I already tried `git mv` but it gave me `fatal: renaming 'Frameworks' failed: Invalid argument`

Comment: "from NTFS point of view a.txt and A.txt are the same thing - so Git tries to preserve that as most users would expect" -- not exactly true. They are the same for some operations and different for others. For example, renaming one to the other is supported on Windows (but not on Linux, this may be a bug in their driver, or maybe whoever implemented it didn't know of this feature).

Comment: HFS+ case insensitivity sucks!!!! Plus, a lot of software doesnt support case-sensitive HFS

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to host on Github, you can use the rename function on their website. Had to change the casing for 5 files and found it worked really well.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem and couldn't get a new folder name (different case) to change on remote repos. I found that the easiest solution was just to move the file out of the repo and commit. Triggering a delete action. Then re-add and when I added, it came in with the proper case.