# Git repository in Visual Studio Team Services case senstive

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

So I "tidied" up some folder naming conventions on my Windows 8 dev machine setting the naming convention of everything to lower case where before there had been a mixture of lower and proper.

Upon my next commit, which was substantial, I found that the source tree had been "duplicated" in multiple places. Cursing a Team Services network related error, I deleted that last commit and tried again. Same thing.

Then it dawned on me that I'm using a git repository. Git being created by "some guy" Torvalds, a Linux kernal dev among other things and from my very limited exposure to *nix remembering that it is a case sensitive environment. SO now in between cursing "some guy" Torvolds I've never met, I've started to wonder how I get out of this situation and why o why has this not been addressed with at least a warning prompt in Team Explorer??

Which button do I click to resolve this issue or am I going to have to waste some time manually addressing this nonsense all by myself?

Update:

In response to Edwards comment.

[image]

So **1** is the original source casing for the first source folder and new lower casing for the second source folder. Now it's either missing 10 or so other projects for that solution or you have to click it multiple times to get all the projects to display. When all the projects display the casing of the folders is: Source > Source rather than: Source > source.

So it's like Team Services cant make up it's mind.

**2** is the new lower casing of the source folders: source > source.

It is simply broken, click on the folder and it's just says loading but never does.

These are examples at this level, at other levels in the folder tree it does similar things.

Basically Team Services Explorer is now unusable.

Comment: Git on Windows (both on the command-line and in Visual Studio) should set `core.ignorecase = true` which should provide case-insensitive but case preserving semantics in most places.  Can you illustrate some of the problems you're seeing?

Comment: checkout this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921153/git-file-rename That should get you there.