# Atlassian sourceTree not track change the folder rename with case Insenstive like "Abc" renamed "ABC"

Tags: git

I have a folder created with name "Abc" in Git repository, due to some naming convention I planned to change the folder name "Abc" to "ABC", when I do this it's not tracking still my folder name showing that as "Abc"
 does anybody face a similar problem?

Comment: What Git version is your Sourcetree using? The embedded one? Or the system one?

Comment: thank you @VonC  I am using Git version 2.16.2 and the Embedded one

Comment: The embedded one might be too old: try the system one.

Comment: @VonC I just tried with System one, but no luck, i did not see any changes

Comment: Is your system Git (the one in the $PATH) the 2.16 one? If yes, can you try and upgrade it to 2.19.2?

Comment: thank you @VonC, after upgrading the 1.19.2 and configure to SourceTree to System, its worked for me.

Comment: @VonC correction here, I just upgraded to 2.19.2, in my previous comment I just put 1.19.2, typo mistake

Answer (score 0):

The [OP ch-sandeep-kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4384361/ch-sandeep-kumar) confirms in the comments:

- configuring SourceTree to use the System Git, not the embedded one (which is often much older)
- upgrading to the latest Git 2.19.2

Then the rename (like [`git mv`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3921179/6309), but through SourceTree) does work.