# Git sensitive case in files names when do a rebase

Tags: git, rebase, case-sensitive, git-pull

I have two branchs production and master .

in the master branch i create an svg image (**i**con.svg) with **i** lower case, i committed that icon.svg then push to Gitlab, then another developer create another image with **I**con.svg same name same image but with **I** upperCase then he commited that image in production branch.

when he try to do a reabse of his branch to the master branch  he do a git pull  rebase in this way : (`git pull origin master --rebase`)
it gives us Icon.svg unstaged and the D symbol for deleted
a solution that I proposed to delete the icone.svg in the master and commit ..
but that solution doesn't work it gives us the same problem in every rebase
How we can solve this problem, thank you for your help

Comment: Decide which casing is correct and use that casing consistently. Did you push the change to master which deleted icon.svg?

Answer (score 0):

If possible the developer should reset and rebase again.

But first rename the Icon.svg

```
git mv Icon.svg icon.svg
```

Once the case is the same, the new rebase should be easier.

Comment: i ve triied that (but i m in windows 10) when i do that that cmd it shows me : "fatal :error  destination icons.svg exist"

Comment: @djopovitch What version of Git for Windows are you using? As I mention in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3921179/6309, this is supposed to work since Git 2.0.1 (June 2014): https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979063/6309

Comment: i'm using Git with 2.19.2.windows.1 version, but doesn't work (⌣_⌣”)

Comment: i saw the links , it work witth --force , git mv --force Icon.svg icon.svg

Comment: but now i have a problem , when i want to do a checkout to the production branch (to rename the image in the production branch) form master , it refuse to go to the second branch it shows me
`error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        Icon.svg
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting`

Comment: @djopovitch To rename the second branch, it is best to clone the repository a second time, and switch to that branch, rename, commit and push from said second branch.

Comment: @djopovitch Regarding git mv, would that work with Git for Windows 2.28? 2.19 seems old at this point.

Comment: @djopovitch Or try with, in the repo: `git config core.ignoreCase true` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreignoreCase)