# How do I change the extension of many files in a directory?

Tags: bash, powershell, cmd

Suppose I have a large number of files in a directory with `.txt` extension.

How can I change the extension of all these files to `.c` using the following command line environments:

- Powershell in Windows
- cmd/DOS in Windows
- The terminal in bash

Comment: Not sure why this was closed (question seems pretty clear to me) but in any case essentially the same question can be found (open) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382638/how-can-i-bulk-rename-files-in-powershell/13382966

Comment: @OhadSchneider Sort of... unfortunately the title (though not the actually use case) of that one is "How can I bulk rename files in PowerShell?", which is much broader, as are the answers. Smi's answer here is money for extensions. Still, no idea why this is marked as too broad either. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 144):

On Windows, go to the desired directory, and type:

```
ren *.txt *.c
```

In PowerShell, it is better to use the [`Path.ChangeExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.changeextension?view=net-5.0) method instead of `-replace` (thanks to [Ohad Schneider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67824/ohad-schneider) for the remark):

```
Dir *.txt | rename-item -newname { [io.path]::ChangeExtension($_.name, "c") }
```

For Linux (Bash):

```
for file in *.txt
do
 mv "$file" "${file%.txt}.c"
done
```

Comment: Does the % in Bash work like a separator to end the string? like $ in regex?

Comment: `Dir -Recurse` for recursive search

Comment: Dir -r as shortcut for recursive