# How can I bulk rename files in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to do the following:

```
Rename-Item c:\misc\*.xml *.tmp
```

I basically want to change the extension on every files within a directory to `.tmp` instead of `.xml`. I can't seem to find a straight forward way to do this in PowerShell.

Comment: And that's why linux is better

Answer (score 105, accepted):

From example 4 in the help documentation of `Rename-Item` retrieved with the command:

```
get-help Rename-Item -examples
```

Example:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt| Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\.txt','.log' }
```

*Note the explanation in the help documentation for the escaping backslash in the replace command due to it using regular expressions to find the text to replace.*

To ensure the regex `-replace` operator matches only an extension at the end of the string, include the regex end-of-string character `$`.

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\.txt$','.log' }
```

This takes care of the case mentioned by @OhadSchneider in the comments, where we might have a file named `lorem.txt.txt` and we want to end up with `lorem.txt.log` rather than `lorem.log.log`.

Now that the regex is sufficiently tightly targeted, and inspired by @etoxin's answer, we could make the command more usable as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\.txt$','.log' }
```

That is, there is no need to filter before the pipe if our regex sufficiently filters after the pipe. And altering the command string (e.g. if you copy the above command and now want to use it to change the extension of '.xml' files) is no longer required in two places.

Comment: if you specify the -WhatIf argument to Rename-Item it shows the output of the operation without actually renaming anything, which is very useful

Comment: That is actually a bad example in the docs IMO. This code is not equivalent to `ren *.xml *.tmp` (hint: `a.xml.xml`). You want `System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36241702/67824.

Answer (score 19):

This works well too when you're in the desired directory.

```
Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "old","new" }
```

Comment: In powershell `dir` is just an alias for `Get-ChildItem`. `gci` is also an alias (and somewhat more "powershell correct") . Run `Get-Alias -Definition Get-ChildItem` to see this. In any case, your example shows that there's really no need to filter before the pipe, if your `-replace` command sufficiently restricts the "old" value (which your example will not, if you only want target the extension).

Comment: Getting error `rename-item: source and destination path must be different`. That doesn't make any sense. But it still performed the rename????

Answer (score 18):

The existing answers suggest the `-replace` operator, but what if the file is called `a.xml.xml`? Both `.xml` substrings will be replaced and the end result would be `a.tmp.tmp`. Fortunately, there's a .NET method for this:

```
Dir *.xml | rename-item -newname { [io.path]::ChangeExtension($_.name, ".tmp") }
```

([Manish Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26519728/67824) was close with `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` but this is more elegant and probably a bit more efficient, not that it overly matters in this case)

Comment: Also works for files with no extension at all.  Nice!!

Answer (score 5):

Here's another variant that will work.

```
dir *.xml | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName + ".tmp"}
```

`$_.BaseName` will do the "base" name without the (last) extension.

Comment: Two things to note: `dir` is just an alias for `Get-ChildItem`; and the filter is using wildcards (which is probably desirable in this context as `MyXmlReference.txt` won't match) rather than regexes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards. In any case the use of $_.BaseName  is a clever alternative.

Answer (score 4):

a shortened version using the alias would be:

```
ls *.xml | ren -new {$_.BaseName + ".tmp"}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/05-formatting-aliases-providers-comparison?view=powershell-7#aliases
"Aliases can save you a few keystrokes and they're fine when you're typing commands into the console. They shouldn't be used in scripts or any code that you're saving or sharing with others. As mentioned earlier in this book, using full cmdlet and parameter names is self-documenting and easier to understand."

Answer (score 2):

```
dir -Recurse | where-object -FilterScript {$_.Extension -eq ".xml"} | Rename-Item -NewName {[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.fullname) + ".tmp"}
```

use -WhatIf to evaluate the result first

Answer (score 2):

Even easier - remember that the replace search string is a regular expression,

```
dir *.xml | rename-item -newname {$_.name -replace "xml$","tmp"}
```

The "$" represents end-of-string, so the characters "xml" must be the last three chars of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work and is a pythonic i.e simple is better than complex (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) way of doing it (once you are in the directory):

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -file -Filter *.xml;
  ForEach ($file in $files)
  {
  $n = $file.Basename
  Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination "$n.tmp"
  Remove-Item "$n.xml"
  }
```