# PowerShell Change File Extension

Tags: powershell, file-extension

Changing file extension of files in a folder if the file was created yesterday.

This is to change the file extension path from .comh to .txt

```
if ($countFiles.Count -gt 0)

    {

    foreach ($f in $files)

      {

     if ($f.CreationTime -gt($(Get-Date).AddDays((-1))))

      {
        #Changing of extension      
      }
```

Comment: take a look at what you get from `@(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $env:TEMP -File)[0] | Get-Member` for some ideas about what properties are provided with `FileInfo` objects. [*grin*]

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,

Comment: Can you please elaborate your requirements ?

Comment: You could try `Dir *.comh | rename-item -newname { [io.path]::ChangeExtension($_.name, "txt") }`. I got this from here [How do I change the extension of many files in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120326/how-do-i-change-the-extension-of-many-files-in-a-directory) and it works fine for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get all the properties of that file in `$f` , use `Rename-Item` cmdlet to rename it,  you would build the new name from the existing by changing the extension.

```
#Changing of extension
$NewName = $F.BaseName + '.txt'
$F | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName
```