# I am unable to change the extension of a multiple files using the powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

To change the extension of files located at: C:\Users\mohit singh\Desktop\spotlight, I typed the following command in the PowerShell

```
C:\Users\mohit singh\Desktop\spotlight> ren *.* *.jpg
```

But I get the following error:

```
ren : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is not valid. Change the value of the "path"
argument and run the operation again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ren *.* *.jpg
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Item], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the extension of many files in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120326/how-do-i-change-the-extension-of-many-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: Close Reviewers: I had considered proposing the linked question, but OP's problem is actually a lack of understanding of the different command interpreters on Windows. If desirable, this could be migrated to SuperUser but I leave the decision to collective wisdom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to use the [`ren`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ren) command from within PowerShell. However, `ren` in Powershell is an alias to [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7) which is a *different command*. Powershell and cmd are different shells that use different command interpreters.

Your simplest option is just to run your command from a `cmd` window, instead of Powershell.

But if you wanted to use Powershell, you can do this by getting every file in the current folder, piping it to `Rename-Item`, then using the [ChangeExtension .Net API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.changeextension) to change its extension (which is safer than simple string replacement).

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Rename-Item -NewName { [io.path]::ChangeExtension($_.Name, "jpg") }
```

If you want to act on subfolders too, add `-Recurse` to `Get-ChildItem`.