# How can I rename multiple files in the GitHub repository at once?

Tags: git, powershell, github, file-rename, batch-rename

I created a repository on the web service 'GitHub', to which I uploaded files one by one or in a group via the web interface from the browser. The files are placed in folders of different nesting depth. The files have different extensions.

Now I needed to rename 157 files in the repository according to the following principle:

```ps
00-00_file-name.ext   # before
00-000_file-name.ext  # after, added '0'
```

These are templates. There can be different extensions instead of `.ext`, I use `.cpp` and `.h`. The `file-name` can be of different lengths. Instead of `00-00`, there can be `00-01`, `00-02`, ..., `01-00`, `01-01`, ..., `02-00`, `02-01`, `02-02` and so on. That is, I needed in the second number (after the hyphen `-`) three digits instead of two.

I know [how to rename](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-files/renaming-a-file) files one by one through the web interface, but I don't know how to rename many files at once through the 'GitHub' web interface.

I cloned the repository to my computer. I wrote a PowerShell script to rename 157 files and renamed these files in the cloned repository with it. After that, I created one commit with all the renames and sent the changes to the original repository on 'GitHub'. Below I will briefly outline the details on the points. (I work on the 'Windows 10' operating system, I use the '[Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/)' program from the command line. I use 'PowerShell' version 7 as a shell. I use 'Windows Terminal' as a terminal emulator.)

1. Cloning a repository to my computer:

```
PS C:\Users\Илья\source\repos> git clone https://github.com/ilyachalov/learncpp-com-examples
```

2. PowerShell script (in the file `rename-files.ps1`, UTF-8 encoding without BOM, CRLF line endings) for renaming files:

```ps
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse |
    Rename-Item -NewName {
        $_.Name -replace '^(\d\d)-(\d\d)_(.*)', '$1-0$2_$3'
    }
```

I also wrote a version of the script that does the same thing, but still outputs messages to the console about the progress of renaming and the final results:

```ps
$total = 0
$renamed = 0
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse |
    Rename-Item -NewName {
        $old = $_.Name
        $new = $old -replace '^(\d\d)-(\d\d)_(.*)', '$1-0$2_$3'
        $script:total++
        if ($old -ne $new) {
            Write-Host "$old --> $new"
            $script:renamed++
        } else {
            Write-Host "$new"
        }
        $new
    }
"Total files checked: $total, including renamed: $renamed"
```

Starting renaming (before using the script, I put it in the target folder and it checks the subfolders in the target folder too; after renaming, the script from the target folder should be deleted so that it does not get into the commit):

```
PS ..\repos\learncpp-com-examples\chapters> .\rename-files
```

3. Creating a commit:

```
PS ..\learncpp-com-examples> git add --all
```

As far as I understand, in this case, the `git add --all` command executes `git rm 'old-name-file'` and `git add 'new-name-file'` for each file, and the 'Git' system diagnoses file renaming. (There's a book [about it](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository).)

```
PS ..\learncpp-com-examples> git commit -m "Renaming a group of files (157)"
```

4. Sending changes to the original 'GitHub' repository:

```
PS C:\Users\Илья\source\repos\learncpp-com-examples> git push origin main
```

In the end, I succeeded, but I'm curious if there are more optimal ways to do the same. After all, I'm new to 'GitHub' and may not know something.

**My questions.** Does GitHub have tools for group file processing via the web interface and through other interfaces? Is it possible to write a script for renaming files in PowerShell more optimally than I did? I couldn't use the `git mv` command, is it possible to use regular expressions in this command? What are more convenient programs (tools) for renaming files on 'GitHub'?

Comment: Just use whatever tool for renaming. Renaming (and copying for that matter) is not concepts which exist as part of gits commits. All renaming and copying is detected when a log/blame or similar command is run.

Comment: @Kim In my case, in step 3, the `git add -all` command executes `git rm 'old-name'` and `git add 'new-name'` for each file, and the 'Git' system diagnoses that the renaming has occurred (as I understand it). Is that what you meant? I'll add this to my question.

Comment: @Kim You write "Just use whatever tool for renaming". I used a PowerShell script. But I wrote my question because I wanted to find out how other people do the same operation. Could you recommend certain tools?

Answer (score 0):

> I couldn't use the `git mv` command, is it possible to use regular expressions in this command?

I [got a hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984722/git-rename-many-files-and-folders) from the users of the 'Linux' system how to use regular expressions with the `git mv` command in this case, even though it does not support them. I rewrote the proposed method in PowerShell:

```ps
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object {
        $old = $_.Name
        $new = $old -replace '^(\d\d)-(\d\d)_(.*)', '$1-0$2_$3'
        if ($old -ne $new) {
            $path = $_.DirectoryName
            Invoke-Expression "git mv $path\$old $path\$new"
        }
    }
```

After running this script, you do not need to form an index using the `git add --all` command, you can immediately create a commit using the `git commit` command. This is stated in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv) of the `git mv` command.