# Git merging moved and renamed file

Tags: git, egit

In one branch I renamed file.
In other branch I moved file.
I merged master branch with both branches.
Now I have two files in master branch and no conflict during merge. Is Git supposed to behave like that? I would expect at least warning.

Edit: Console gives me waring. So it is egit issue. (Egit is eclipse plugin)

Comment: Did you use `git mv` or did you rename/move the files using shell commands?

Comment: I used shell. According [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094269/whats-the-purpose-of-git-mv) it should not matter.

Comment: The accepted answer in the question you linked has a comment (referring to git mv): "Also it has a few safeties built in". Maybe this is one of the cases?

Comment: @user482745: it does matter, re-read the post you linked

Answer (score 2):

Behaviour is normal, because you renamed the file without `git mv`; git correctly detected file rename, but did not commit deletion of old file, so you have both files now after merge.

Using `git mv`, or `mv` followed by `git rm oldfile` it correctly leads to a merge conflict.

```
Initialized empty Git repository 
$ echo "hello" > hello.txt
$ git add hello.txt && git commit -m "first"
[master (root-commit) 708ec5f] first
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 hello.txt
$ git branch mybranch
$ git mv hello.txt hello2.txt
$ git commit -m "renamed"
[master 00c68ed] renamed
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename hello.txt => hello2.txt (100%)
$ 
$ git checkout mybranch
Switched to branch 'mybranch'
$ mkdir test
$ git mv hello.txt test
$ git commit -m "moved"
[mybranch 044e091] moved
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename hello.txt => test/hello.txt (100%)

$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git merge mybranch
CONFLICT (rename/rename): Rename "hello.txt"->"hello2.txt" in branch "HEAD" rename "hello.txt"->"test/hello.txt" in "mybranch"
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Comment: No, It has nothing to do with not using git mv. Using git mv gives same result.

Comment: not for me; if you `mv` but  don't `git rm` the old file, the latter will stay. I reproduced a simple case here and I get a merge conflict

Comment: see transcript of my test repo, following the case you describe (move in one branch, rename in the other, and merge). I correctly get a merge conflict