# Does there need to be a specific command to have git recognize the movement of a file?

Tags: git, github, commit

I committed some changes to my project, and one of the things done was the movement of a file into another folder. I did the usual:

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit something"
git push origin
```

But on my github account, when looking at the project, the file I moved is still in the location before the movement. The file is also in the folder I moved it to. When looking at where it was moved, there is no commit info which I would think should happen, but there is on the old one. Is there a reason why this is? I am sorry if that is not very clear, please let me know if it needs to be made clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you move or rename a file, the old file reference is still there. You need to remove the file from git by...

```
git rm filename
```

And then commit.

Comment: What happens if I already deleted it and its not in my local git repo? How do I remove it from github to reflect that its also missing locally?

Comment: The same way. You can run this command, and see that git will remove this file.

Comment: I did, but its not reflected on github. It definitely removed it locally now for sure. But I can't push that change. DO I have to make a more significant change or something?

Comment: Nope, I was just being dumb. I didn't commit it apparently. At least not correctly. You have been most helpful. Is there another way that I can just remove files without telling github directly, and have it include it automatically as well as moving them? Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Well as far as I know, this is the only way. And it makes sense also, to manually ask git to remove a file, if it has been removed or renamed. You could try and check for other ways.

Answer (score 1):

There is `git mv old new`; you use it like the normal `mv` command. If you already added the new file, remove the old one from git: `git rm old`

It's basically just sugar for the following commands:

```
mv old new
git add new
git rm old
```

Also have a look at [What's the purpose of git-mv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094269/whats-the-purpose-of-git-mv) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for that. Will definitely look at that,