# Git - handling a merge where files have merged

Tags: git, merge, branch

The problem we're facing is simple, I'm just not sure how to properly handle it. We have a branch that re-organized files and we're ready to merge master into that branch. The problem is that by now master has changed quite a bit.

Ex:

```
Master:
- file1
- file2
- file3

Our branch:
- directory1/file1
- directort2/file2
- directroy3/file3
```

How do I tell git the new location of the files so that the auto-merge can work properly?

Thanks.

Comment: If they contain similar contents, Git should be clever enough to figure that out by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should always move files using the `git mv` command to ensure that the new file structure is tracked properly. git can handle the merging as long as it is aware of which files are which.

Comment: Git does not record rename information in its commits. It only detects them during log (or merge)

Comment: I stand corrected, was assuming git and mercurial operated the same in this regard. just found this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094269/whats-the-purpose-of-git-mv

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before and it can be a pain. This isn't really a solution but one way to make it less painful is to frequently rebase the branch against the Master.