# git merge does not remove files

Tags: git, msysgit

I try to merge two branches, say `br2` into `br1` (on `br1` `git merge br2`). `1.txt` is a file which is present on both branches. In `br2` this file is moved into another directory `1.txt` is now in `sub/1.txt`. After merge is done I have two files `1.txt` in `br1`: `1.txt` and `sub/1.txt`, that is strange.

If I apply commit which moved `1.txt` file with `cherry-pick` file is correctly moved to subdirectory.

Why is not it moved (but copied) into subdirectory during merge?

```
$ git --version
git version 1.8.1.1
```

Comment: You have msysgit tagged on your question. Is it correct to say that you're using Windows? Have you investigated the possibility that it may be an issue with case-insensitivity for file names on Windows systems?

Comment: @Cupcake, file names are in the same case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer. There was a problem with merge base. Basically diff from head to merge-base did not contain file deletion, so that is why git removed files with cherry pick and did not with merge.

Comment: And the solution to the problem was?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you didn't removed explicitly the file on br2?

The usual way to move a file is using git mv. That would be:

```
git checkout br2
git mv 1.txt sub # Moving 1.txt to sub/ using git mv command
git commit

git checkout br1 
git merge br2    # You should see now the file 1.txt only on sub/
```

If you made something like that, one possibility is that for some reason 1.txt was "introduced" on the top folder by some commit that is on br1 and not on br2, therefore doing the merge between those branches will keep them both.

Maybe I can understand better if if you post `git log <hash-of-commit-where-you-moved-the-file> --stat --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit` and/or `git log 1.txt` on the branch where is not supposed to be.

Comment: `git add .` is [superfluous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094269/whats-the-purpose-of-git-mv).

Comment: You're right @antak, git mv already contains the git add operation. Answer edited!