# git move is taking files as new

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, bitbucket

Trying to move files in a project with git with intellij-idea, the refactor is done by the IDE modifying imports and packages and some files of the project are removed and added again because in GIT there is a percentage of modifications that above it, the files are detected as new.

I would like to modify this percentage no to detect files as new. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, a Git move operation is the same as a remove and add in one step (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094269/whats-the-purpose-of-git-mv)).

You can however detect certain amount of changes as move operations with `git log`. Take a look at the following option in the `git-log(1)` man page:

```
-M[<n>], --find-renames[=<n>]
   If generating diffs, detect and report renames for each commit. For
   following files across renames while traversing history, see
   --follow. If n is specified, it is a threshold on the similarity
   index (i.e. amount of addition/deletions compared to the file’s
   size). For example, -M90% means Git should consider a delete/add
   pair to be a rename if more than 90% of the file hasn’t
   changed. Without a % sign, the number is to be read as a fraction,
   with a decimal point before it. I.e., -M5 becomes 0.5, and is thus
   the same as -M50%. Similarly, -M05 is the same as -M5%. To limit
   detection to exact renames, use -M100%
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, but the fact is that when rm and add the history is deleted as well and I don't want this. It should be a way.

Comment: @raulgomis: the history is not "deleted", in part because there's actually no "history" for any *file* at all.  "File history" is instead computed using the commits.  E.g., if commit A has a set of files that includes blob ID=<hash>, and commit B has a set of files that includes blob ID=<samehash>, then that file's contents (regardless of its name) are *exactly the same* in A and B.  However, `git log --follow` and `git log --diff` use a similarity-detector, since changing a single bit in any file changes its hash.  This is ... hard to explain without diagrams and maybe some theory.

Comment: Thanks torek, yes, I understand that commits in GIT are based on its content not on file names. A possible workaround is to move the files with git mv in the first commit and then do the changes/refactors in the code and perform another commit. But I was wondering if there was another way to do it in the same commit, without having to refactor everything.