# bundle install causes validation error after moving file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, gemspecs

In my gem development directory, I moved the file *lib/project/module.rb* to *lib/project/helpers/module.rb* and then did

> bundle install

This gave me an invalid gemspec error

> project at /path/project did not have a valid gemspec. This prevents
>   bundler from installing bins or native extensions, but that may not
>   affect its functionality. The validation message from Rubygems was:
>
> > ["lib/project/module.rb"] are not files

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem occured because gemspec uses git to validate the presence of required files.

Instead of doing a normal mv

> mv lib/project/module.rb lib/project/helpers/

It's better to do a git mv

> git mv lib/project/module.rb lib/project/helpers/

After reverting the move and doing the git mv, bundle install worked without any validation errors.

It is also better practice in general to do git mv rather than mv in a git repo, because it can potentially keep you commits looking cleaner. [What's the purpose of git-mv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094269/whats-the-purpose-of-git-mv)

Comment: Actually a simple `git add . --all` removed this warning!

Answer (score 3):

Probably you have modified name of that file and didn't commit that changes.

```
git add .
```

Will solve the problem.