# How do I rename a file in JGit

Tags: rename, file-rename, jgit

How do I rename a file in JGit. That is, given a working file named file1.

The command line would be:

```
git mv file1 file2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent to `git mv` in Git. `git mv` is just a short hand for

```
mv oldname newname
git add newname
git rm oldname
```

[(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094269/whats-the-purpose-of-git-mv)

Respectively, use `File.renameTo()` or, since Java 7, `Files.move()` to move the file and then

```java
git.add().addFilepattern( "newname" ).call();
git.rm().addFilepattern( "oldname" ).call();
```

to update the Git index.

The paths given to `addFilePattern()` must be relative to the work directory and path segments must always be separated by slashes (`/`) independent of the file system in use.

Note, that Git does not track renames or moves. When using the `--follow` option with `git log`, it uses heuristics to try to detect renamed or moved files (see [Is it possible to move/rename files in Git and maintain their history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314652/is-it-possible-to-move-rename-files-in-git-and-maintain-their-history))

Comment: Will this still retain the git file history?

Comment: I've edited the post, does that answer your question?