# Starting to use Maven on existing project without losing GIT history

Tags: java, git, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to integrate Maven into an existing project. Using IntelliJ IDEA, I've tried the following steps:

*Right click on project -> Add Frameworks Support... -> Checking Maven and pressing OK*

The above works great; except that it drastically alters (read: copy -> delete -> paste) 
the project structure. The change is fine - except that GIT believes that all files have been deleted and re-created (without history) in another folder.

**How to integrate a project with Maven without losing the GIT history?**

Comment: If you `git rm <changed file>` and `git add <changed file>` does `git status` show the summary for the staged file changes as separate delete and create or one single modify?

Comment: @mbs They are listed as separate delete and create. I tried "git rm src/*" and then doing git add src/main/*", which doesn't solve the problem. All history is still gone.

Comment: What is the diff between the old and new versions of the files? Can you supply a short example based off one file? `git diff HEAD` or `git diff --cached` when the changes are staged (can't remember off the top of my head which you should do).

Comment: @mbs After I've done the git rm/add or before? Many thanks for helping, by the way!

Comment: After. You don't need to commit the changes

Comment: @mbs When re-doing the steps again to retrieve the diff output (git rm src/com/* ; git add src/*), git started to notice the file similarities and outputted RENAME instead of add/delete. Now, when using git log --follow instead of gitk, everything works perfect! Many thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

With git there is no difference between

```
copy -> delete -> paste
```

and simple

```
move
```

or even

```
git mv
```

which is equivalent to

```
copy -> delete -> paste
git add --all .
```

The problem might be in your diff tool. What are you using to view the diff?

Try

```
git add --all .
```

and commit and see what happens.

Also see

[What's the purpose of git-mv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094269/whats-the-purpose-of-git-mv)