# Git recursive mv files

Tags: git, bash, mv

I'm trying to add version numbers to all javascript files in a directory so that changes to the files won't be cached by our users.

How can I move all Javascript files that are in several directories within one directory?

With the example file structure:

```
js/
--home/
----main.js
--apps/
----main.js
--handlers.js
--ajax.js
```

I would like to do something like `git mv -r js/*.js js/*.1.js` to append a `.1` to the filenames.  Obviously there isn't a flag for recursion for git mv, so I'm wondering what my options are to do something similar.

Comment: You don't need a recursive flag to `git mv`.  You don't need `git mv` at all.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094269/whats-the-purpose-of-git-mv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Globstar](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-pattern-matching) (bash >=4)

```
shopt -s globstar # Set the SHell OPTion globstar
for f in **/*.js; do
  git mv "$f" "${f%.js}.$version.js"
done
```

To move everything to a single directory:

```
for source in **/*.js; do
  dest="${source%.js}.$version.js"
  dest="$destination/${dest##*/}" # Strip off leading directories and prepend actual destination
  git mv "$source" "$dest"
done
```

## Find

You can use `find`, but it's almost the same, so save this for where you need Bash 3 or POSIX sh portability (OS X, for example).

```
find . -iname '*.js' -exec sh -c 'for f; do
  git mv "$f" "${f%.js}.$version.js"
done' _ {} +
```

Comment: That `**.*.js` makes it go into a single directory?  Also, what's the `shopt` and `globstar`?

Comment: @bozdoz `globstar` is just the recursive version of a regular `*` and is written `**`. `shopt -s` sets the option to true (false by default in [tag:bash]), allowing it to be used.

Comment: @bozdoz updated with a way to move everything to a single destination – I wasn't sure that's what you wanted at first.

Comment: I didn't need `shopt` or `globstar`.  Also I added it to a makefile like so: `for f in js/**/*.js; do git mv "$$f" "$${f%.js}.$(v).js"; done`