# Automatically remove files in GIT repository after renaming them

Tags: linux, git, unix

I usually does the following with

```
$ mv file1.py file2.py
$ git add .
$ git rm file1.py
```

How can I skip the last step? So that whenever I add the newly name
files it will automatically remove the old one `file1.py` in the git repository.

I know I can do `git mv file1.py file2.py`. But in my workflow I tend to do many `mv` commands and prefer to add and commit them at the very end.

Comment: git mv file1.py file2.py

Comment: Probably this answers the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094269/whats-the-purpose-of-git-mv

Comment: @Ambrish you may want to read all of the question first

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stage all current files you can do it with `git add -u` So you can try the following combination:

```
git add . #add new files
git add -u #stage removed files
```

#### Example

> ```
> lol4t0@lol4t0-VirtualBox:~/gtets$ mv foo bar
> lol4t0@lol4t0-VirtualBox:~/gtets$ git status
> On branch master
> Changes not staged for commit:
>   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
>   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
>
>   deleted:    foo
>
> Untracked files:
>   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
>
>   bar
>
> no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
> lol4t0@lol4t0-VirtualBox:~/gtets$ git add -u
> lol4t0@lol4t0-VirtualBox:~/gtets$ git status
> On branch master
> Changes to be committed:
>   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
>
>   deleted:    foo
>
> Untracked files:
>   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
>
>   bar
>
> lol4t0@lol4t0-VirtualBox:~/gtets$ git add .
> lol4t0@lol4t0-VirtualBox:~/gtets$ git status
> On branch master
> Changes to be committed:
>   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
>
>   renamed:    foo -> bar
> ```