# What is the command to move multiple files from 1 directory to another directory in a project

Tags: git

Objective:
Want to move files (multiple files) from 1 directory to another directory in a project.

For example, consider the below folder structure:

```
Project/TRUNK/
```

so the files like abc.java, xyz.java and Hello.java are in the directory:

```
Project/abc.java
Project/xyz.java
Project/Hello.java
```

Practically there are 100 files present in the Project directory. Want to move the files to the TRUNK directory.

I tried to use:

```
cd Project
git mv abc.java TRUNK
```

but that moves files one by one. Any suggestion on a git command where the files can be moved at once, will be very helpful.

Comment: `git mv Project/*.java Project/TRUNK`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you’ve discovered, you can use the [`git mv`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv) command to move files.  To move multiple files at the same time, you can combine this with a *glob* (shell feature that expands a special pattern to multiple filenames), e.g., to move all files in the current directory whose name ends with `.java` run

```
git mv *.java TRUNK
```

For more information on how to use shell glob patterns to match specific files see the following resources:

- [Greg’s Wiki article on glob patterns](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)
- [POSIX specification of shell pattern matching](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13)

Answer (score 1):

[Git doesn't track file copy/move/rename operations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1094269/7976758) so you can move files any way you want, for example with your preferred filemanager, then update index with `git add -A .` and commit.