# how do you move folders into the bitbucket repository without removing other folder?

Tags: bitbucket

Suppose that you have a repository in bitbucket and you need to create a new folder inside the bitbucket repository and move your files there.
The way that I am moving it removes history, all the previously saved files in the repository and replaces the new one.

I found some similar questions here but they are old and they did not work out for me.

Please advise!

**Edited: the wat that I am doing :**

```
git init
git add .

git commit -m "my new commit"

git remote add origin https://.....

git push -f origin master
```

This removes any other code.

Comment: Use `git mv` to move files in a git repo.

Comment: what would be the rest of git mv ?

Comment: How are you currently doing it?
"The way that I am moving it removes history, all the previously saved files in the repository and replaces the new one.", can you explain?

Comment: I edited my post. pls review it

Comment: Never use `-f` with push if you want to preserve history.

Comment: it won't work without -f actually.

Comment: Why are you adding a remote and pushing? Why not just move the files into the new folder like in my answer? I'm sorry, I seem to be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Git tracks exactly what matters, namely "collections of files".

`git mv oldname newname` is pretty much like `mv oldname newname; git add newname; git rm oldname`

It mostly depends on your client I think to track renaming of files. Sometimes it works, but if the content is changed drastically then it considers it as  a new file.

An other question on here that discusses this issue.

[What's the purpose of git-mv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094269/whats-the-purpose-of-git-mv)

Update:
https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_does_Git_not_.22track.22_renames.3F

> As a very special case, 'git log' version 1.5.3 and later has '--follow' option that allows you to follow renames when given a single path.

Mail by Linus on this topic.

> Git has a rename command git mv, but that is just for convenience. The
>   effect is indistinguishable from removing the file and adding another
>   with different name and the same content.