# Is it possible to rename a git file after doing a regular mv?

Tags: git, file

I've renamed a few files in my git repo, but I forgot to use `git mv` to rename those files. I'd like to make my commit reflect the renamed files, instead of showing a deletion and an addition to the repo. Is it possible to do something like that?

Or would I have to create a kind of macro that uses `mv` to move the file back to the original name, and then `git mv` to rename it once again, like so:

```
function fixmv() { mv $2 $1 && git mv $1 $2 }
```

If there is a built-in way to do this using git, I'd love to hear.

Comment: You can do `mv` without `git mv`: you need to add both files to the index: `mv $1 $2 && git add $1 $2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the purpose of git-mv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094269/whats-the-purpose-of-git-mv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About three years ago, I wrote [a script to do this](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/git-mv-after)—`git-mv-after`, to be invoked as `git mv-after` a la `hg mv --after`—but all you really have to do is run `git add old-name new-name`.

(My script is extra-fancy as it does a bunch of checks to make sure that the rename is safe.)

I do think `git mv` should include a `--after` flag, so that Git isn't deliberately dumber than Mercurial here. :-)  But it is pretty minor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; the easy way is to run `git add new-name` and `git rm --cached old-name`. git doesn't track renames specifically; they're just a deletion from one name and an add of the same content at a new name.
`git rm --cached` tells it not to complain about the fact that the file you're asking it to remove doesn't exist.